# Como chamar um método com parametros nomeados usando uma hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Gostaria de saber se tem como passar parâmetros para um método de parâmetro nomeado via hash. Tem como repassar os parâmetros que sobram para outra funçãom como no exemplo a seguir?

```
params = {key: "value",key2: "value2"}
def func(key1: nil, key2: nil, **args)
    other_func **args
    ...
end
func params
```

Ocorrência do problema no rails:

```
#No controle
@session = SessionUser.new(params[:session_user].merge(session: session))

# classe SessionUser
def initialize(session: nil, email: nil, password: nil, **args)
    @session = session
    @email = email
    @password = password
end
```

Comment: Seu exemplo funciona.

Comment: Diz que o numero de argumentos esta errado, de certo considera a hash como um parâmetro apenas e se fosse via array (*args) funcionaria, mas não e isto que preciso

Comment: A sintaxe de hash `**` só é válida a partir da versão `2.0` do Ruby. Antes disso você deve usar um parâmetro do tipo hash explicitamente.

Comment: A minha versão é 2.1.5, adicionei abaixo a ocorrência do problema para ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei o erro, no caso passei uma hash que possuía chaves não símbolos, o mesmo problema foi resolvido nesta questão :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394206/ruby-2-keyword-arguments-and-actioncontrollerparameters

No meu caso, usando o rails posso utilizar o método '.symbolize_keys'
para quem esta apenas usando o Ruby também é possível resolver desta maneira:

```
my_hash.inject({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[k.to_sym] = v; memo}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse método do `ActiveSupport`

http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/symbolize_keys